# Skip Main Menu at the second application launch

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.5

I'm new here and a beginner in Xcode, and I'm trying to do an app with 5 pages. The first one is a menu page with 4 buttons, each leading to a different page. When you first launch the application you can choose which page to go to (from the other 4). What I'd like to do is make the application skip the menu page at the second time you launch it (go directly to the page you selected before). Can anyone give me some directions on where to find tips about this, or give an example related to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"secondTime"]==YES) {
    switch ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"nextTime"]) {
        case 1:
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstViewController animated:YES];

            break;
        case 2:
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];

            break;
        case 3:
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdViewController animated:YES];

            break;
        case 4:
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:forthViewController animated:YES];

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return;
}


 }


-(void)btnClicked:(id)sender{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:[sender tag] forKey:@"nextTime"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"secondTime"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
switch ([sender tag]) {
    case 1:
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstViewController animated:YES];

        break;
    case 2:
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];

        break;
    case 3:
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdViewController animated:YES];

        break;
    case 4:
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:forthViewController animated:YES];

        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user selects a page I would store that selection into the `NSUserDefaults`...

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:chosenPageIndex forKey:@"selectedPage"];
```

(chosenPageIndex is an NSNumber of the page index).

Then when the app launches you can do this...

```
NSNumber *prevSelectedPage = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"selectedPage"];

if (prevSelectedPage != nil) {
    //use this bit to move to the selected page using the page number stored in prevSelectedPage
}
```

Thats how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSUserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this purpose.

When the user selects an option add it to `NSUSerDefaults` like:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:selectedPage] forKey:@"Selected_Option"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

And when the user opens the app again, in tha `applicationWillLaunch` method of appdelegate, you can retrieve the data like:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSNumber *page =   [defaults objectForKey:@"Selected_Option"];
int selected   = [page intValue];
```

And do what you want according to the selected page. At first load the selected will be equal to 0.